# Adding a remove button to each listView element

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm learning android and struggling with this part. I have a simple activity with a button that adds entries to a listview in an array list. The point is down the road to make a favorites tab for my app to display items that you have selected as a favorite in another activity. I haven't progressed that far yet so for now I'm just playing with this and would like to add remove buttons on each row to remove the "item." Here is what I have so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
int click=1;


public void addItems(View v) {
    listItems.add("Soon to be item : " + click++);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

XML file

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="1"
tools:context="com.favtest2.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addBtn"
    android:text="Add New Item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="addItems"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you list item you are using standard layout from the framework:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

There's no button.

Create you custom layout with a button "Delete" instead.

But actually you don't even need button - you can click right on you list item to delete it itself.

Look for info about OnItemClickListener.

Here is pretty good tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Upd:

Add to your code method, something like:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    listItems.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: I see that this link also makes use of "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" and mentions removing list items?

Comment: Yes you can add OnItemClickListener to the whole item, so you not need to have special btn inside

Comment: I've been playing around with that now and I can't seem to do it/see how it should be done with what I have currently. Any tips?